# MySQL Select enclosure

Tags: mysql

I have a code like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE integer NOT IN (
SELECT varchars FROM table2 WHERE id = 1)
```

`varchars` consists of numbers separated by comma (1, 2, 3, 4 etc.) This code doesn't work correctly because the `SELECT` part between brackets gets enclosed by quotes `' '` and MySQL only reads the first integer before the first comma. How do I get read of those quotes or make that code work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE integer NOT IN (
SELECT varchars FROM table2 WHERE id = 1 FIELDS ENCLOSED BY 'NULL')
```

didn't help me either since it causes error #1064.

Comment: Huh? Please expand on: *because the `SELECT` part between brackets gets enclosed by quotes ' ' and MySQL only reads the first integer before the first comma*.

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table 2 ON FIND_IN_SET(integer,varchars)  AND id =1 WHERE varchars IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks Mihai, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table 2 ON FIND_IN_SET(integer,varchars) AND id =1 WHERE varchars IS NULL
```

This one is a correct answer mentioned by Mihai in the comment section above. Version of Sebas also works but when varchars for id = 1 in table2 doesnt exist it returns NULL while it should return all integer from table1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT varchars FROM table2 WHERE id = 1) AS t
WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(integer, t.varchars)
;
```

- `CROSS JOIN` so the query is just executed on its own (as long as it returns a record)
- [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) searches into a comma separated list of values.